# Why am I not getting notifications for changes on shared calendar events?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I've successfully [created a webhook subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to listen for changes on a shared calendar (I got a 201 Created response back from the create subscription endpoint) with the following POST body:

```
{
    "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
    "notificationUrl": <my_https_app_webhook_url>,
    "resource": "/me/calendars/<calendar_id>/events",
    "expirationDateTime": "2020-03-06T12:30:27.606347+00:00",
    "clientState": <secret_token>
}
```

If I then create an event on that shared calendar with 1 attendee (aside from myself, the organizer & owner of the shared calendar) and that attendee declines the event, I don't receive a notification at my subscription notificationUrl.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: My guess is that responses do not update the event object itself, thus not triggering any notification. In that scenario, is the event change key updated?

Comment: The change key for the event on the shared calendar does not change after the attendee declines the event on their calendar. So it would seem your theory is correct. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: I'd say so. The reasoning behind it is that anytime you update an event with invitees either through UI or API, it sends and update email to the invitees. Having the attendee response update the event object would trigger a maelstrom of emails. So this list is probably stored separately behind the scenes, which doesn't update the event object when the attendees respond, which in turns doesn't trigger a notification.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
   "changeType": "created,updated",
   "notificationUrl": "https://mynotification.url.com",
   "resource": "users/adminuser@oadmin.onmicrosoft.com/events",
   "expirationDateTime":"2020-03-03T14:09:27.121Z",
   "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}
```

Make sure you have added,ChangeType:**created,updated**

Comment: I've included "updated" in the changeType field -- that's not the issue here. I updated my question with the POST body I used to create the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior as the attendee's responses do not update the event object itself, thus not triggering a notification.
I'd recommend you add this as a suggestion to [UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/)

Comment: Alright, well in that case do you have a suggestion for how to get attendee response statuses on shared calendar events via the graph API? It seems like not only do attendee responses _not_ generate a notification but also that they don't update the shared calendar even period. . . see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60515773/why-doesnt-my-shared-calendar-event-show-the-updated-attendee-response-statuses). If that's the case, why is there a field for attendee response statuses on shared calendar events in the Outlook UI, if it will never be updated?

Comment: to be clear: it doesn't seem to update the event object itself but it should update the attendee objects that are linked to the event. So periodically polling the status on attendees would be the only way to track attendance. I looked at your other question, I'm not sure why the UI isn't updated in your scenario.