# Why doesn't my shared calendar event show the updated attendee response statuses in Office365?

Tags: outlook, calendar, office365, outlook-calendar

If I create a calendar in Office365 and share it with user A, then create an event on that calendar with user A as an attendee, user A's response status is never reflected on the shared event. It always just says, "user A didn't respond." on my calendar. Even when viewing the shared event from user A's calendar, it says "You didn't respond."

For example:

1. I create an event on a shared calendar and add user A as an attendee

[image]

2. User A sees two calendar events, one on their default calendar and one on the shared calendar

[image]

3. User A declines the event on their default calendar (they have no response options on the shared calendar event)

[image]

4. The event on User A's default calendar disappears. The event on the shared calendar, as seen by User A does not show their response status

[image]

5. The event as seen on my calendar also does not show User A's response status

[image]

This happens regardless of the level of permission that User A has on the shared calendar. Even in the case where the calendar isn't shared with User A at all (they only see the event on their default calendar), their response status never shows on the shared calendar event.

Comment: For context this is related to the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60497361/why-am-i-not-getting-notifications-for-changes-on-shared-calendar-events
The UI could be a caching issue or something similar, if you try the same scenario in the UI but then query the shared event attendee information in the Graph explorer, what do you get?